# Webshop, Security & CakePHP

Tags: security, cakephp

I am building a webshop for which I want to ensure the security is good given we are handling money and other sensitive stuff. I am also relatively new to CakePHP and web programming in general and is not totally across the wonderful world of website security. I was wondering if there are people out the who you be so kind to provide security tips and best practise for webshops in particular which are built using CakePHP? Does these posts, [Cakephp Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870427/cakephp-security), [What makes CakePHP secure, and how can we increase it's security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282408/what-makes-cakephp-secure-and-how-can-we-increase-its-security), cover all the relevant security risks or are there more things I should be thinking about in specific for a webshop?

Comment: there is also http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/10/05/cakephp-security/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that the post covers all of the security possible issues of your cake, but you may want to Google "Cake Exploits". If I were you, I wouldn't use CakePHP for building robust secure web app, actually I wouldn't use any open source Framework or app. I would build it myself!
Think about scalability and functionality of the framework too. CakePHP isn't one of the best performing out there! I'd recommend to take a look at the Yii framework. And again when it comes to security think about the security of your app comes first, would you like to use the code of someone else that you're not 100% sure what the code does? I wouldn't!
Some more detailed information about the CakePHP you may want to take look at this detailed comment: [PHP Framework or not (Cake PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12476057/php-framework-or-not-cake-php/12482342#12482342)

Good luck!

Comment: So, you say that open source code cannot be secure. IMHO, this is not true. Popular open source frameworks are carefully tested by thousands of programmers and security experts around the globe because their source is openly available. After a vulnerability is found developers fix it. Using an own framework don't necessarily add to the security, especially if it is closed source. Moreover, the experience and intelligence of thousands of developers around the globe will always beat ones of an individual programmer. The fact that you don't see a vulnerability doesn't mean there is no any.

Comment: When speaking of security and scalability I wouldn't use a framework. In matter of fact I bet most people don't even know how to use the frameworks correctly due to the long documentations and time required. On top of that that same community of security experts is able to see the source code and hack you 100 times easier knowing every single line of your code. In enterprise environment there's no place for unknowns and mistakes.

Comment: How many sites do you think get hacked before a security hole is found and security patch is released? 0.5-1% out of hundreds of thousands? That's a pretty big number. Are you going to be one of them?
Keeping up with system and the framework updates, dependencies and versioning is not an easy task.

Comment: Regarding security as example search https://www.google.com/search?q=cakephp+2+exploits and you'll get over 60000 results related to the cakephp exploits, what happens, if you're late 1 day with your framework update? There are always new features and new bugs and security holes, because the software evolves which doesn't always get noticed immediately by the "security experts".
Regarding the closed (in house) development there are Q&A and security analysts which audit your code. It's never a good idea to audit your code by yourself.

Comment: I understand you point. Of course when vulnerability and exploit for it is found you will be in a risk group until you a patch is released. But what makes you think that your own framework will be perfect and will not have any vulnerability? This sounds more like security via obscurity and actually does not introduce any benefits, especially vs a professional hacker who do not need a source code to break into the system. Really, enterprise is no place for such mistakes. That is why the majority of them use tested and proven frameworks like Zend or fork them to build their own on top of it

Comment: How people use a tool is entirely their own issue. You cannot blame a framework if someone does not adhere to its recommendations and writes a bad code. Actually, it is much easier to screw everything up with a home-made framework than a renown one. For example, Kohana 's ORM automatically escapes all sql stuff when you use it. When you use Kohana and do not use its database classes with built-in security and got hacked, well, it is entirely your fault and not Kohana's. The developer should devote some time to studying his toolset before starting using it at work.

Comment: And with the same logic... It is the same with the self developed framework, if you don't know what you're doing better stay away from the programming :)

Comment: )) if you do not know what you are doing, better start learning right away.)) if you are that confident that you have developed a one-and-only perfect un-breakable framework, I think you should start selling it and make a fortune.)) Or may be post its code on github, etc so that the rest of us, plain non-gifted developers learn something from its all-catching security handling techniques.)) This way to will write your name into the history. But  apart from kidding, anything can be, was and will be hacked. It just takes a truly professional hacker focused on your product.

Comment: There never was and will not be a perfectly secure solution, because vulnerability can be found anywhere - even in protocols themselves. That's why none of the software products can ever be secure, including big software product name like Facebook, Gmail, etc.